# Is there a way to order a non-commutative symbol before a commutative symbol in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

The code below outputs an expression that we would identify visually as b * a. I want the form a * b where the commutative symbol is *after* the non-commutative symbol.

Is there anyway to do this (in notebook)?

```
from sympy import *
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)

a = Symbol('\\mathbf{a}', commutative = False)
b = Symbol('b')

a*b
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in SymPy, but if you want this kind of fine-grained control, you might want to give Cadabra (https://cadabra.science) a shot. It can talk to SymPy under the hood for various manipulations, but uses its own internal representation of mathematical expressions, and avoids rewriting expressions if you do not want that. You can do the above with (slightly expanded):

```
{a,b}::SortOrder;
{a,c}::NonCommuting;

ex:= b a;
sort_product(ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I can think of is a custom printer. Here's one customizing `StrPrinter` by simply reversing the tuple of args in printing a multiplication after the original code has ordered them. Also, to be honest, I have no idea whether this maneuver has any other unwanted ramifications...

Code for `StrPrinter` can be found in https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d5dd53389fed3180aacc4dd1986b62802a2d19b6/sympy/printing/str.py

```
from sympy import Basic, Function, Symbol
from sympy.printing.str import StrPrinter
from sympy.printing.precedence import precedence, PRECEDENCE

class CustomStrPrinter(StrPrinter):
    def _print_Mul(self, expr):

        prec = precedence(expr)

        # Check for unevaluated Mul. In this case we need to make sure the
        # identities are visible, multiple Rational factors are not combined
        # etc so we display in a straight-forward form that fully preserves all
        # args and their order.
        args = expr.args
        if args[0] is S.One or any(isinstance(arg, Number) for arg in args[1:]):
            factors = [self.parenthesize(a, prec, strict=False) for a in args]
            return '*'.join(factors)                

        c, e = expr.as_coeff_Mul()
        if c < 0:
            expr = _keep_coeff(-c, e)
            sign = "-"
        else:
            sign = ""

        a = []  # items in the numerator
        b = []  # items that are in the denominator (if any)

        pow_paren = []  # Will collect all pow with more than one base element and exp = -1

        if self.order not in ('old', 'none'):
            args = expr.as_ordered_factors()
        else:
            # use make_args in case expr was something like -x -> x
            args = Mul.make_args(expr)
            
        # * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
        # * Here's the actual customization:  *
        # * Reverse args                      *
        # * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
        args = (e for e in args[::-1])

        # Gather args for numerator/denominator
        for item in args:
            if item.is_commutative and item.is_Pow and item.exp.is_Rational and item.exp.is_negative:
                if item.exp != -1:
                    b.append(Pow(item.base, -item.exp, evaluate=False))
                else:
                    if len(item.args[0].args) != 1 and isinstance(item.base, Mul):   # To avoid situations like #14160
                        pow_paren.append(item)
                    b.append(Pow(item.base, -item.exp))
            elif item.is_Rational and item is not S.Infinity:
                if item.p != 1:
                    a.append(Rational(item.p))
                if item.q != 1:
                    b.append(Rational(item.q))
            else:
                a.append(item)

        a = a or [S.One]

        a_str = [self.parenthesize(x, prec, strict=False) for x in a]
        b_str = [self.parenthesize(x, prec, strict=False) for x in b]

        # To parenthesize Pow with exp = -1 and having more than one Symbol
        for item in pow_paren:
            if item.base in b:
                b_str[b.index(item.base)] = "(%s)" % b_str[b.index(item.base)]

        if not b:
            return sign + '*'.join(a_str)
        elif len(b) == 1:
            return sign + '*'.join(a_str) + "/" + b_str[0]
        else:
            return sign + '*'.join(a_str) + "/(%s)" % '*'.join(b_str)
        
def custom(expr, **settings):    
    p = CustomStrPrinter(settings)
    s = p.doprint(expr)

    return s

a = Symbol('\\mathbf{a}', commutative = False)
b = Symbol('b')

custom(a*b)
```